# Azure eventhub with spark structure streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I'm new to spark structure streaming and azure event hub and have written a code as below:

```scala
val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()
import spark.implicits._

val body=incomingStream.select(incomingStream.col("body").cast("String"))
val query=body.writeStream.format("memory").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation",fileLocation+checkpointFolder).queryName("Body").start()
val data=spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from Body").map(x=>x(0).toString())

val result=spark.sqlContext.read.json(data)
result.write
  .partitionBy(partitionColumn)
  .option("path",fileLocation+eventHubName)

query.awaitTermination()
```

I'm unable to fetch data in val data variable and not able to write it to azure data lake. I can see in logs that writestream is creating table in memory as `Body` but nothing in the output. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try move `query.awaitTermination()` before you read the data and see if it works.

Comment: okay i think i found a solution. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Spark-Structured-streaming-format-quot-memory-quot-is/m-p/199355

Comment: How can i truncate the table once it is processed and written to data lake so i do not get old data?